Uipath connect to SQL Server and use bulkinsert - get System.Exception error
I have an Excel file with 750,000 records. I first use read range to load it into a data table.
To avoid issues with large volumes of data, I used a For Each loop to split the data and perform bulk insert into the database (100,000 records each time).
According to the log, my For Each loop completed, but it still throws the following error:

System.Exception: Could not retrieve the result of the job execution. This might be because a message was too large to process.

I would like to know the possible reasons and if there are any solutions.
If there is anything else I need to provide, please let me know, and I will supply it as soon as possible.
This is my log and process flow:
Flow and Log
I already tried delay, made sure everything is completed, and also tried using a procedure, but still got this error.

First of all. Welcome. Good question. Could you share this file so its easier for someone to check your specific issue? What happens on 1000er bulks?
